# HDB3 Waveform: Determining the bit sequence

Tags: digital-communications, binary

I was asked to determine the bit sequence of a given HDB3 waveform. I understand that if there are three consecutive 0's then the fourth in that sequence must be a violation pulse. In this example however, I'm confused. Prior to receiving three 0's, the last violation pulse and the last pulse were of positive polarity. After the three 0's there is a negative pulse but how are you supposed to know  whether it's just a negative 1 or if it's a negative violation pulse? All I see is three 0's followed by a negative pulse but from what I understand, it could be either a violation pulse or a normal pulse. What is it that I'm not getting?

[image: Here is the question that I was asked]

As seen in the image above, the part that's confusing me is the 10th bit (the first negative pulse). I got that the 6th bit was a violation pulse because it was preceded by three 0's. Any help is much appreciated. By the way, the answer is that it's a negative 1.

Comment: You are using "HDB3" like we're all supposed to know what that is without a proper definition, and your picture is unreadably small.  Closing as *unclear*.  If you hurry up and fix this before 4 more close votes accumulate, we may be able to help.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: HDB3 is a well-known term to anyone who's worked in digital telephony, and easily looked up by anyone else. Penalizing a new user based on your own lack of knowledge is not appropriate here. However, I agree that the tiny picture is a problem.

Comment: HDB3 is a Line Coding scheme used in digital communication and I assumed anyone answering the question would understand what it meant thus defeating the purpose of me explaining it. Apologies about the image. As Dave said, I'm new here and I thought stack exchange would sort out all the image formatting. I've made it bigger but I'm not sure how to make it a better quality image as it was a screenshot. It's still legible though.

Answer (score 2):

In [HDB3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_AMI_code#HDB3_.28European_E-carrier.29), any sequence of 4 zeros in the data is replaced by either 000V or B00V.

Therefore, you just need to look at your given sequence and identify the bipolar violations:

```
Line sequence: 0 + 0 0 0 + 0 0 0 - 0 0 0 + 0 - 0 0 0 - + 0 0 + 0 0 0 - + 0
                   _ _ _ V                     _ _ _ V _ _ _ V
Actual data:   0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
```

Any group of four bits ending in a V is really four zeros in the data. Any other pulse that is not a V is a one in the data. Therefore, the pulse in the tenth bit position is a one, because it has the opposite polarity from the previous pulse.