# In HDB3, does a 1 have opposite polarity to the last 1, or to the last V?

Tags: encoding

I am trying to understand HDB3, and in particular trying to find out whether the picture below which shows the encoding of a bitstring in HDB3 is correct or not:
[image]

From what I understand, a `1` will have the opposite polarity to the last `1`. So since the red `1` is `-`, the blue `1` should be `+`.

But in the picture, the blue `1` is `-`. Is this correct? Is it because the `0` in black is `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is correct. A `1` must have the opposite polarity of the previous pulse, regardless of whether that pulse was part of a 4-zero substitution or another `1`.

Otherwise, it would constitute another `V`, which would be illegal.

Comment: What if the last pulse of the `1` is a `0`? So in the above diagram, if we add a `0` between the black `0` and the blue `1`, what will the polarity of the blue `1` be?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. A `1` is never a `0`; it is always either `+` or `-`. Perhaps [this previous question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/203686/11683) on the topic will help clarify matters.

Comment: Sorry, by "last pulse", I mean the previous pulse. So again, what would the encoded string be if there is a `0` before the blue `1` and the black `0`?